# Mover un metodo a otra clase Android Estudio

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, json

Tengo el siguiente Medetodo en la clase MainActivity.java, pero quisiera moverla a otra clase igual.java , el problema es q no quiero q sea extends  AppCompatActivity, lo que pasa es que no se como modificarla para q se adapte a una clase normal, Consiste en buscar un jugador en base a peticiones PHP

```
private void buscarJugador(String URL){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("nombres"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de Conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas mover el método a otra clase y no deseas que esta clase extienda de la clase `AppCompatActivity`, básicamente debes modificar tu método para que este reciba el `Context`, además el método debe tener el modificador `public` para que pueda ser accedido desde otra clase.

```
public void buscarJugador(String URL, Context context){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Toast.makeText(context, jsonObject.getString("nombres"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error de Conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Para llamar el método instancia la clase y llama el método definiendo la url y el Contexto, ejemplo:

```
   TestClass tc = new TestClass();
   tc.buscarJugador("https://......", getApplicationContext());
```